# Slide in and out element according to div id scroll position

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, slide

i am trying to hide and show an element when a div reach the top of the browser.
i read few threads and write this code

```
function hidebtn() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('.triger').offset().top,
    distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

  var x = document.getElementById("u94");

  if (distance < 1) {
    $(x).animate({'top': '-100px'}, 300);
  } else {
    $(x).animate({'top': '0px'}, 300);
  }
}

window.onscroll = hidebtn
```

for same reason it doesnt work or if to be more specific it works with a huge delay.

if i change the condition code to

```
if (distance < 1 ) {
    x.style.display = "none";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
}
```

it works fine but i really like to use the sliding animation

you can see it in [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zivo/agfhkcbk/4/)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animation function is triggered many times and it will cause some hard to debug issues. A better solution is to use css and some additional checking. This way the hide/show will be triggered only when needed.

Css

```
.hide {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

JS

```
function hidebtn() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('.triger').offset().top,
    distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

  var x = $("#u94");
    var isHidden = x.hasClass('hide');

  if (distance <= 0 && !isHidden) {
    x.addClass('hide');
    console.log("hide");
  } else if (distance > 0 && isHidden) {
    x.removeClass("hide")
  }
}

window.onscroll = hidebtn
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/andreiTn/yag47gyn/

Comment: Thank you
I choose this answer because there is no delay in the animation.
I added 

.show {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-100%) !important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out !important;
}

for show animation and make few more improvements
you can see it here https://jsfiddle.net/Zivo/1k0yt8rL/22/

Answer (score 1):

`onscroll` is called multiple times when the user scroll. You can set a little timeout to remove excessives calls:

```
var scrollTimer = null;

function hidebtn() {

    if (scrollTimer) {
        clearTimeout(scrollTimer);  // clear previous timer
    }

    // set timer while we wait for a pause in scroll events
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        scrollTimer = null;  // timer done here
        console.log("ok");

        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
          elementOffset = $('.triger').offset().top,
          distance = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

        var x = document.getElementById("u94");

        if (distance < 1) {
          $(x).animate({'top': '-100px'}, 300);
        } else{
          $(x).animate({'top': '0px'}, 300);
        }
    }, 100); // delay time
}

window.onscroll = hidebtn
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ludo6577/a8Lnkq6a/1/)